# Why setTimeout is used in counter up animation in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I tried to find the answer for this question but could not find it anywhere.

Here i have my animation code :

```
let counters = document.querySelectorAll('.counter');

   counters.forEach(counter => {
       counter.innerText = 0;
       let target = +counter.dataset.count;
       let step = 1;

    let countIt = function () {
        let displayedCount = +counter.innerText; // 0
        if(displayedCount < target) {
            counter.innerText = displayedCount + step;

            setTimeout(countIt, 1);

            // countIt(); // here if i call countIt directly then my counter animation does not work. 
                          //but with setTimeout it works.
        } else {
            counter.innerText = target;
        }

    }
    countIt();

   })
```

So my question is why this is happening ? Anybody can explain me what is going on under the hood?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers don't repaint the page when JavaScript code is running on the main JavaScript thread. By just calling `countIt` directly, you're doing all your updates during the same JavaScript job, and then the browser repaints the page when it's done. By using `setTimeout`, you break the updates into multiple JavaScript jobs scheduled *roughly* 1ms apart, so the browser has a chance to repaint between them.

You can find details in the [HTML specification's *Event Loops* section](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-loops) and the JavaScript specification's section [*Jobs and Host Operations to Enqueue Jobs*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-jobs). They use slightly different terminology: a JavaScript "script job" is largely an HTML "task," and a JavaScript "promise job" is one kind of HTML "microtask."

You might also be interested in [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame), which provides a way to ask for a callback just before the page is repainted. Right now, your counters are updating multiple times between repaints, which happen typically about once every 16.667ms. So the browser isn't painting every value you put in the counter DOM element.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was reading about setTimeout. they say that setTimeout will be run only after all js code executed. So in this case is it waiting to run whole loop and recursion and and when main code is finished then only setTimeout code runs?

Comment: @TrueCode - The `forEach` loop runs to completion. The code within each `forEach` callback schedules a single timer callback. When each of those callbacks runs, it schedules another callback. And so on until you reach the target.

Comment: I am sorry but what does it mean `schedules a single timer callback.` ?

Comment: @TrueCode - That's what `setTimeout` does. When you call `setTimeout`, you're asking the browser to call the function you pass in after the number of milliseconds you gave it have passed. The call to the function is the callback from the timer.

Comment: Okay i got it. you mean setTimeout. So all scheduled timer are running when forEach finishes. And it runs in the interval of 1ms thats why it has time to repaint the browser in that 1ms? Is it correct how i understood ? )